# Calendar in ICS lockscreen

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, calendar, lock-screens

I'm searching for a way to display a couple of calendar events on the lockscreen of Android 4.x ICS.

I found [Lockscreen Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.lockscreenCalendar) but it doesn't support ICS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My personal solution would be to use [Widgetlocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&hl=en) and put a widget on the lockscreen, such as the built-in ICS calendar widget. But that's just me :)

Comment: I found that one before but I wasn't sure because I didn't see a calendar in the screenshot directly. I'll give it a try. Thanks!